# Ubuntu 20.04 nearing EOSL

Tags: esm, ubuntu-pro

I see Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is EOSL in Apr 2025.

I see ESM until 2030. As part of open source will this be available free of cost or is any cost required?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Pro access is a paid service for companies, but individual users can get a free token for up to 5 machines (including either physical or virtual machines) by logging in to the [Ubuntu Pro Dashboard](https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard).

Also see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro) to learn what an Ubuntu Pro subscription covers.

Comment: i mean for ESM do we need paid subscription

Comment: "Free token for up to 5 machines" means you don't have to pay as an individual user. If you're a company, then you need to pay.