# USN-5931-1 Why is this security patch only for ESM/ Ubuntu Pro

Tags: security, lts, patch, esm

18.04 LTS still has general support until April 2023, the patch for USN-5931-1 was released March 7th 2023.  As march is before April, and this is a security patch, this should have been included in support offered via LTS.  Why was this decided to be only offered for ESM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are ESM Apps, and how do they relate to Ubuntu Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro)

Answer (score 1):

```
guiverc@d7050-next:/de2900/lubuntu$   rmadison python3.8
 python3.8 | 3.8.0-3ubuntu1~18.04.2  | bionic-security/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 python3.8 | 3.8.0-3ubuntu1~18.04.2  | bionic-updates/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 python3.8 | 3.8.2-1ubuntu1          | focal                    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 python3.8 | 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7 | focal-security           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 python3.8 | 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.7 | focal-updates            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

The packages fixed are found in ***universe*** in *bionic* or 18.04 ( see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.8 where you'll note it is a 'universe' package) meaning the security fix requires ESM or Pro.

Only packages in 'main' get security fixes for non-ESM/non-Pro systems. Security fixes for 'universe' packages is a new feature added by Ubuntu Pro.

Comment: For more details please see https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-faq/34042  (*which maybe updated on occasion too*)