# Ubuntu 16.04 ESM / 18.04 ESM / 20.04 ESM / 22.04 ESM / 22.10 : FFmpeg vulnerabilities (USN-5958-1) after running nessus scan

Tags: apt, package-management, security, ffmpeg

So I have run several nessus scans to check for vulnerabilities on my ubuntu 20.04 setup and I keep getting this vulnerability.

I have followed this: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5958-1 and trying to update every package there for ubuntu 20.04 but I get 2 packages that have conflicts:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec-extra58 : Conflicts: libavcodec58
 libavfilter-extra7 : Conflicts: libavfilter7
```

So I don't know how to solve this and resolve the vulnerability.

EDIT: I could install the packages but now my problem is that following the link above, when I try to update packages like:

`libavcodec-extra - 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1+esm1` it gives me an error:

`E: Version '7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1+esm1' for 'ffmpeg' was not found`

It happens for every package finished in `*+esm1`.

Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is a dependency problem, that has nothing to do with vulnerabilities. Please see below.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ArturMeinild that helped to update the packages. But it's true I still have the vulnerability, maybe it's because I cannot install the packages ending in `+esm1` as it tells me for example `E: Version '7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1+esm1' for 'ffmpeg' was not found`. I don't know what to do then

Comment: Also see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro). You're not missing anything that you had before. ESM patching for Universe is a new service. Nessus is a "cheap" solution that only scans for package names.

Comment: Oh I understand now, okay so in my case I don't have ubuntu pro so I cannot install ESM packages. Then if I have every package from https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5958-1 updated to its version (without the esm1 flag) why I'm still getting the vulnerability?

Comment: Because upstream security patches was never provided to Universe before - and it isn't on Arm or other platforms either. You have 2 choices: Subscribe to Ubuntu Pro, or just live with it.

Comment: Oh, I get it, thank you very much, that answers everything

Comment: Yes thank you, @ArturMeinild game a perfect solution :)