# How to update ESM apps?

Tags: updates, esm

I recently installed Ubuntu and while going through the documents on getting started I encountered this:

```
 Installed packages with an available esm-apps update:
libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56 libpostproc55 libswresample3
libswscale5
```

[image]

How can I update these ESM apps?

using sudo apt install and sudo apt upgrade
[image]
it shows already to newest version and set to manually installed Idid not install any of these package manually.
and now when i run pro security-status --esm-apps
[image]
if they are updated then why do the above command keeps on showing recieved 7 security update each time I run

"pro security-status --esm-apps".

Is there someone else manually updating these packages for me?
am I doing something wrong here and why are these 2 packages gjs and libgjs which have been kept back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are ESM Apps, and how do they relate to Ubuntu Pro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the 7 installed packages that are available in the esm-apps update open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56 libpostproc55 libswresample3 libswscale5
```

or simply run `sudo apt upgrade` .

The two packages that have been kept back - gjs and libgjs - are phased updates that will be updated later after the phased updates have been tested on a small group of Ubuntu operating systems that were selected to receive updates for these two phased update packages (gjs and libgjs) at an earlier date.