# Software Update

Tags: updates, 22.04

The software updater has instructed me to upgrade to Ubuntu Pro before I can install the software updates. I am told to get a token, but I don't know how to do it. I have created the Ubuntu Pro account, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: First you need to retrieve your Ubuntu Pro token from the [Ubuntu Pro dashboard](https://ubuntu.com/pro). To access your dashboard, you need an [Ubuntu One account](https://login.ubuntu.com/). If you still need to create one, be sure to sign up using the email address used to create your subscription. [See full instructions here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/subscription),

Comment: You should be able to get the basic Ubuntu updates without getting Pro. Only [ESM updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro) require Ubuntu Pro.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been able to update the software.

Comment: I will convert my comments to an answer. Please accept the answer as correct by pressing the gray check mark next to the answer and turn it green. This will mark your problem as solved and help others find the right answer to the same question

Answer (score 1):

## Security and Basic updates

Security fixes and basic updates are available to all users of Ubuntu whether you join Pro or not. Only [ESM updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452497/what-are-esm-apps-and-how-do-they-relate-to-ubuntu-pro) require an Ubuntu Pro subscription. I can't tell you if you need Ubuntu Pro or not. Some Ubuntu users have it some don't want it. Irrespective of Ubuntu Pro you should always keep your computer updated with security fixes.

## Getting Ubuntu Pro Token

Ubuntu Pro is free for personal use in up to 5 computers. The full instructions on how to attach your computer to Ubuntu Pro is available at [the official website](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/subscription).

First, you need to [create an Ubuntu Pro account](https://login.ubuntu.com/) if you don't have one. Log in.

Second, you need to copy your **Ubuntu Pro token** from the [Ubuntu Pro Dashboard.](https://ubuntu.com/pro)

Finally you need to paste the copied token at the end of the command below in a terminal of the computer where you want Ubuntu pro:

```
sudo pro attach <your_pro_token>
```

where `<your_pro_token>` should be replaced by the token you have copied from the Ubuntu Pro website.

Hope this helps